# My database query isn't working when I use ? in the statement

Tags: php, pdo

Is there any reason why this returns 0 results in my user database

```
function googlelogin($db, $email){
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail = ?",$email)->fetchArray();
  ...
```

When this returns 1 result...

```
function googlelogin($db, $email){
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail = 'myemail@email.com'")->fetchArray();
```

Even though $email = myemail@email.com

Thank you

Comment: You tagged as "mysqli" but `fetchArray()` is a PDO function. That vote to close as unclear, is mine btw.

Comment: Can you suggest where I post this, please? I copied this line from another function which works fine.

Comment: you are using PDO the wrong way. Refer to the accepted answer in the linked post, it has a PDO example.

Comment: You posted in the right place. It's just that you used the "mysqli" tag which doesn't support the `fetchArray()` PDO function. The question was closed with a duplicate; try that out.

Comment: Thank you. Managed to work it out. There was a space after $email. Solved it with trim($email); . Was driving me mad.